# Error says static member function was undefined, but I defined it?

Tags: c++, static

I must be missing something obvious, thanks for the help.
Coding in C++. IDE is Clion.
In my main.cpp I call a `Parser::parse(tokenList)` function.
The Parse function is declared in Parser.h as `static std::string parse (std::vector<Token*>& tokenList);`
I define the function in Parser.cpp as `std::string Parser::parse (std::vector<Token*> &tokenList){return "";}`
In my main.cpp file I `#include "Parser.h"`
When I build my project I get `undefined reference to 'Parser::parse(std::vector<Token*, std::allocator<Token*> >&)'`
Am I defining incorrectly?
I have similar code with the same problem. In that example, including the .cpp file instead of the .h file resolves the issue. Why would that be (yes, I know including the .cpp is bad practice)?

Comment: Descriptions of code pale in comparison to code.

Comment: You're supposed to compile all .cpp files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your posts, for example to improve their [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and including a [mcve].